# Trying to understand how java enums work

Tags: java

I have written the following Java class, that is based on the EXPENSES application in the SAMPLES folder of Google Web Toolkit source code. The code is below.

My goal is to understand how java enums work and I thought this might be a good starting point. I have gone through material on the internet about ENUMS, and I get the basic concept. However I am still struggling to understand this piece of code.

This is my code:

```
public class Expenses {

    public static enum Approval {
        BLANK("", APPROVED("Approved"),DENIED("Denied"));

        /**
         * Get the {@link Approval} from the specified string.
         * 
         * @param approval the approval string
         * @return the {@link Approval}
         */
        public static Approval from(String approval) {
          if (APPROVED.is(approval)) {
            return APPROVED;
          } else if (DENIED.is(approval)) {
            return DENIED;
          }
          return BLANK;
        }

        private final String text;


        private Approval(String text) {
              this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
              return text;
          }

        public boolean is(String compare) {
              return text.equals(compare);
          }

    } 

    public static final String[] DEPARTMENTS = {
          "Engineering", "Finance", "Marketing", "Operations", "Sales"};


}
```

Eclipse complains  about APPROVED and DENIED.

```
 The method DENIED(String) is undefined for the type 
     Expenses.Approval
    - The method APPROVED(String) is undefined for the type 
     Expenses.Approval
```

What is the BLANK(...) thing? Is it some kind of datastructure?
How does that work?

---

All I am looking for is a way to understand this code, and get rid of the compilation errors, before trying to work more on this code.

Comment: Check your parentheses.

Comment: This is a better Enum tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html . Take time to read the tutorials, don't just blindly copy code.

Comment: Thank you. It was the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a parenthesis issue. Add line break to increase readability .

```
BLANK(""),
APPROVED("Approved"),
DENIED("Denied");
```